# thymeleaf spring standard dialect: using template

Tags: spring, layout, themes, thymeleaf, dialect

Hello I have some problems with templating pages.
I am returning from controller a view called `list`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="layout/template">
    <div layout:fragment="pageContent">
        <p>LIST</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

And I would like to put this into template where I have a lot of html stuff and:
`<div layout:fragment="pageContent">Demo static page content</div>`

But I am getting in web browser only list view.

How to put one view returned from controller to template using SpringStandardDialect?

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand correctly, you want to inject that fragment which is called pageContent into some other html page (lets call it main.html for sake of it.

First thing to do is change the div in list to the following:

```
<div th:fragment="pageContent">
      <p>LIST</p>
</div>
```

then in your main.html you would call the fragment via:

```
<div th:include="list::pageContent"></div>
```

or

```
<div th:replace="list::pageContent"></div>
```

Btw "list::pageContent" indicates that its in base folder, if its located in folder called example then it would be "example/list:pageContent".

here is the great example on Thymeleaf website: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments

Hope this helps, if not let me know.

Comment: How about returning view in controllers? Is it stay the way it was first in spring?

Comment: Returning fragment from controller is as easy as doing 'return "myTemplate :: myFrag"'. So if you want to use REST, you just pull the fragment.

Comment: So if I wonna return `home` view and put it to template. I am just doing in controller: `return "home";`?

Comment: Yes, have you had a chance to look through the Thymeleaf tutorial i linked? If not jump on it and read it up, there are a lot of powerful combinations you can do. There is multiple ways of returning views as well based on your controller configuration.

Comment: Cursorily for now. I am in decision between Spring Standard Dialect and Layout Dialect. Dont know which one to use.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly but fair enough. The answer is there and will take care of that problem for you.

Comment: A soon I arrive home I will test it. For now I have working solution with decorator and layout dialect. But for spring I should use spring dialect with this fragments. I will give a try.